# What type of soil should I use to backfill around my recently extend well?

Tags: water, well

My well was buried so I had a well driller put an extension on so that it extends above ground. Now I need to add soil to fill around and slope away.  The soil that was dug out and put back in around the electrical and line to the house was clay. I need about another yard of material to finish backfilling. What type soil should I use?  More clay?  Should I have put clean granular fill around the house line then clay?

Answer (score 5):

Clay is a pretty good choice.

Around the top of a well, what you want is both slope and soil type to prevent surface water going down beside the well casing.

Comment: Yeah, clay. In particular bentonite clay is commonly  used for sealing surface water out of the ground